# How do I use Lambda to get EC2 information via CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

The following flow is executing Lambda.

1. monitor log files in EC2 with cloudwatch logs
2. Detects monitored strings with a metrics filter
3. Execute Lambda with alarm

I would like to know how to get the following information within Lambda.

- Path of the log file being monitored
- Instance name
- Instance id
- Alarm name

I am writing in python and trying to get it using boto3.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this in 2 ways:-

1. Create a cloudwatch event bridge rule with event type as **cloudwatch
   alarm state change**.

- Whenever your alarm will be in an alarm state it will send an event, configure the target of this event type as lambda function or sns topic, whatever suits your need.

Sample event from this rule

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "c4c1c1c9-6542-e61b-6ef0-8c4d36933a92",
  "detail-type": "CloudWatch Alarm State Change",
  "source": "aws.cloudwatch",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2019-10-02T17:04:40Z",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "resources": ["arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-east-1:123456789012:alarm:ServerCpuTooHigh"],
  "detail": {
    "alarmName": "ServerCpuTooHigh",
    "configuration": {
      "description": "Goes into alarm when server CPU utilization is too high!",
      "metrics": [{
        "id": "30b6c6b2-a864-43a2-4877-c09a1afc3b87",
        "metricStat": {
          "metric": {
            "dimensions": {
              "InstanceId": "i-12345678901234567"
            },
            "name": "CPUUtilization",
            "namespace": "AWS/EC2"
          },
          "period": 300,
          "stat": "Average"
        },
        "returnData": true
      }]
    },
    "previousState": {
      "reason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [0.0666851903306472 (01/10/19 13:46:00)] was not greater than the threshold (50.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for ALARM -> OK transition).",
      "reasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2019-10-01T13:56:40.985+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2019-10-01T13:46:00.000+0000\",\"statistic\":\"Average\",\"period\":300,\"recentDatapoints\":[0.0666851903306472],\"threshold\":50.0}",
      "timestamp": "2019-10-01T13:56:40.987+0000",
      "value": "OK"
    },
    "state": {
      "reason": "Threshold Crossed: 1 out of the last 1 datapoints [99.50160229693434 (02/10/19 16:59:00)] was greater than the threshold (50.0) (minimum 1 datapoint for OK -> ALARM transition).",
      "reasonData": "{\"version\":\"1.0\",\"queryDate\":\"2019-10-02T17:04:40.985+0000\",\"startDate\":\"2019-10-02T16:59:00.000+0000\",\"statistic\":\"Average\",\"period\":300,\"recentDatapoints\":[99.50160229693434],\"threshold\":50.0}",
      "timestamp": "2019-10-02T17:04:40.989+0000",
      "value": "ALARM"
    }
  }
}
```

2. Inside your cloud watch alarm there is an alarm action there your can add SNS topic to it and then you can easily get your event information, if you want to process it further,you can add lambda to SNS topic.